# Bootstrap inside row div 100% height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

actually how to make the div inside a row equal to 100% height, i mean the left sidebar will following height, depending on the right content,

just try give a height: 100%; but it doesn't work, some advice will be appreciated

```
<body>
 <div class="content">
  <div class="container main">
    <div class="row 2-col">
        <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 left">
            <p>Sidebar</p>
            <p>Sidebar</p>
            <p>Sidebar</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 right">
            <p>Content </p>
            <p>Content </p>
            <p>Content </p>
            <p>Content </p>
            <p>Content </p>
            <p>Content </p>
            <p>Content </p>
            <p>Content </p>
            <p>Content </p>
            <p>Content </p>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>

html, body, .content, .main, .2-col {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.content {
    background: #a1a1a1;
}
.main {
    background: #666;
}
.left {
    height: 100%;
    background: #333;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.right {
    height: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
p {
    color: #fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x63qtvsh/4/

Thanks

Comment: Are you want same height of sidebar and content or sidebar and content always 100%?

Comment: The sidebar will always follow the content height  @pham-minh-tan

Answer (score 0):

One solution is calculate the height of two columns left sidebar and your right content after DOM ready.
And then dynamically set the the height of both the columns to maximum height.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function sidebarHeight(){
var tallest = $('.right').height();
$('.left').height(tallest);
}
sidebarHeight();
$(window).on("resize", function(){
sidebarHeight();
});
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/x63qtvsh/9/

Note: You will need the jQuery library for this.